# How to get DATE_DIFF in decimal

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My friends are migrating from Netezza to BigQuery. In Netezza "month_between" function gives them back a decimal result. Meanwhile in BQ date_diff is always an integer. Is there a way to get fractional output in BQ?

([their logic](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS6NHC/com.ibm.swg.im.dashdb.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0053631.html))

Comment: isn't this just matter of translating integer number of days(or hours) into float number of month? just checking :o)

Comment: oops, I do have a working answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You could write an UDF:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION months_between_impl(date_1 DATE, date_2 DATE) AS (
    CASE
      WHEN date_1 = date_2 
        THEN 0
      WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_ADD(date_1, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = 1
        AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_ADD(date_2, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = 1 
        THEN DATE_DIFF(date_1,date_2, MONTH)
      WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_1) = 1 
        AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_ADD(date_2, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = 1 
        THEN DATE_DIFF(DATE_ADD(date_1, INTERVAL -1 DAY), date_2, MONTH) + 1/31
      ELSE DATE_DIFF(DATE_ADD(date_1, INTERVAL -1 DAY), date_2, MONTH) - 1 + EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_ADD(date_1, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) / 31 + (31 - EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_2) + 1) / 31
    END
  );

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION months_between(date_1 DATE, date_2 DATE) AS (
  TRUNC(months_between_impl(date_1, date_2),9)
);




WITH
  t AS (
  SELECT DATE("2005-02-02") AS from_date, DATE("2005-01-01") AS to_date, "1.032258064516129" AS Expected
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2007-03-15"), DATE("2007-02-20"), "0.838709677419354"
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2008-03-29"), DATE("2008-02-29"),  "1.0" 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2008-03-31"), DATE("2008-02-29"),  "1.0" 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2005-11-29"), DATE("2006-03-01"),  "-3.096774194" 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("1993-07-01"), DATE("1993-03-31"),  "3.03225806" 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2005-03-31"), DATE("2005-01-01"),  "2.967741935" 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE("2008-03-30"), DATE("2008-02-29"),  "1.032258064516129" 
)

SELECT
  from_date, to_date, expected, months_between(from_date, to_date) months_Between
FROM t;
```

[image]

> added by Mikhail

Below is real run on Netezza showing that above UDF actually returns totally correct result (as for some reason the numbers in `expected` column are not what really Netezza returns - rather correct numbers are under `result` column - which as I mentioned exactly what Felipe's UDF produces)

[image]

Comment: Acknowledgments to my Google teammates that asked and solved this problem internally first.

Comment: Btw, I just run your data on Netezza and my result shows slightly different result that is marked as `expected` - the good news is that it is exactly same as output of your udf with the exception for row #5 - i will add image to your post  - hope you will be ok with it :o)

Comment: Thanks for sharing UDF function, I am able to get 97% of results correct, however in few cases, above function is resulting incorrect values in GCP side vs Teradata

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing the UDF function, I am able to get 97% of the results correctly, however in few cases, the above function is returning incorrect values in GCP vs Teradata.
Here are some of the examples where I am getting different outcomes.

**Teradata SQL:**

```
SELECT 
 months_between(CAST('2026-07-01' AS DATE), CAST('2022-09-29' AS DATE) )  as Date_1 ,
 months_between(CAST('2023-05-01' AS DATE), CAST('2022-09-22' AS DATE) )  as Date_2,
 months_between(CAST('2025-10-01' AS DATE), CAST('2022-09-29' AS DATE) )  as Date_3,
 months_between(CAST('2037-03-01' AS DATE), CAST('2022-09-06' AS DATE) )  as Date_4
```

Date_1 = 45.10, Date_2 = 7.32, Date_3 = 36.10, Date_4 = 173.84

**ON GCP** when using the UDF function, it is returning different values.

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION months_between_impl(date_1 DATE, date_2 DATE) AS (
CASE
  WHEN date_1 = date_2 
    THEN 0
  WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_ADD(date_1, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = 1
    AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_ADD(date_2, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = 1 
    THEN DATE_DIFF(date_1,date_2, MONTH)
  WHEN EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_1) = 1 
    AND EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_ADD(date_2, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) = 1 
    THEN DATE_DIFF(DATE_ADD(date_1, INTERVAL -1 DAY), date_2, MONTH) + 1/31
  ELSE DATE_DIFF(DATE_ADD(date_1, INTERVAL -1 DAY), date_2, MONTH) - 1 + EXTRACT(DAY FROM DATE_ADD(date_1, INTERVAL -1 DAY)) / 31 + (31 - EXTRACT(DAY FROM date_2) + 1) / 31
END
  );

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION months_between(date_1 DATE, date_2 DATE) AS (
  TRUNC(months_between_impl(date_1, date_2),9)
);

SELECT round(months_between(CAST('2026-07-01' AS DATE), '2022-09-29' ), 2) as Date_1,
round(months_between(CAST('2023-05-01' AS DATE), '2022-09-22' ), 2) as Date_2,
round(months_between(CAST('2025-10-01' AS DATE), '2022-09-29' ), 2) as Date_3,
round(months_between(CAST('2037-03-01' AS DATE), '2022-09-06' ), 2) as Date_4
```

Date_1 = 45.06, Date_2 = 7.29, Date_3 = 36.06, Date_4 = 173.74

Not sure why there are differences, even when the majority of values are correct.
I tested the UDF function on 2000 dates.

Comment: That logic is making assumptions about 31 days im a month. That's probably the difference.