# Results difference between months-between function and date_diff function

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform

I am getting two different results running same query in Teradata side vs GCP:
Teradata SQL

```
SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(DATE'1995-02-02', DATE'1995-01-01');
```

returns the result **1.03**

GCP Respond

```
SELECT DATE_DIFF(DATE '1995-02-02', DATE'1995-01-01', MONTH);
```

GCP side is just retuning **1** as value.

According to one of the documentations:
Teradata "The MONTHS_BETWEEN function calculates the fractional portion of the result based on a 31-day month and considers the difference in time components of date_timestamp_value1 and date_timestamp_value2."

I am looking for a function on GCP side which can return same value as off Teradata.

Comment: please use this solution, this UDF is better solution [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53403414/how-to-get-date-diff-in-decimal/75759963?noredirect=1#comment133644535_75759963)

Answer (score 2):

`date_diff` rounds the number down (emphasis added):

> Returns the **whole number** of specified date_part intervals between two DATE objects (date_expression_a - date_expression_b). If the first DATE is earlier than the second one, the output is negative.

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_diff

I couldn't find an equivalent function, but using `DATE_DIFF(..., DAY) / 31` should work.

Comment: Thanks that work for me SELECT ROUND(DATE_DIFF(DATE '1995-02-02', DATE'1995-01-01', DAY)/31, 2) ;